# How to use rename operator in SQL for relational algebra?

Tags: sql, relational-algebra

For example. Consider the relations

```
college(cname, age, height)
college2(name, age, height)
```

How would I use natural join on this such that cname = name?

Comment: Are `college` and  `college2` both table?

Comment: You are not clear. Do you want SQL, for what algebra expression, or do you want an algebra expresssion, for what SQL expresssion? Also natural join is like a projection of an equijoin on columns with the same name, so "such that cname = name" doesn't make any sense. Use enough words, phrases & sentences to say what you mean plus examples that illustrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT c1.*
FROM college c1
INNER JOIN college2 c2 on c2.name = c1.cname
```

this will select all from college, where find cname values in table college2 / column name